# Listviews with EditText behavior

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

i've noticed an extrage behavior on my app that has a ListView with three EditTexts,
the problem is that whenever i select one textedit and move away from focus and come back the text i wrote in the first row i selected either desapears or moves to a different row, also when an edittext is focused and i go down in the list it seems that i have selected the edittext in the same position but 10 or 11 rows after the one im actually focusing(the one i can write to).

any knowledge on that case?

also im new to android so i dont know if thats supposed to happen.
this is the List im using.

```
    public class In_List {
    private int id; 
    private String text; 
    private float a;
    private float Qty; 

    public In_List (int id, String text, float a, float Qty) { 
        this.id = id; 
        this.text = text; 
        this.a = a; 
        this.Qty= Qty;
    }

    public String get_text() { 
        return text; 
    }

    public float get_a() { 
        return a; 
    }

    public int get_id() {
        return id; 
    } 

    public float get_Qty() { 
        return Qty; 
    }
}
```

here is the adapter:

```
    public abstract class List_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<?> ins; 
    private int R_layout_IdView; 
    private Context context;

    public Lista_adaptador(Context context, int R_layout_IdView, ArrayList<?> ins) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.ins = ins; 
        this.R_layout_IdView = R_layout_IdView; 
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
            view = vi.inflate(R_layout_IdView, null); 
        }
        onInsert (ins.get(position), view);
        return view; 
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ins.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return ins.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public abstract void onInsert (Object insert, View view);

}
```

and here is the main activity. it has a popup window that i used to fill the value of Qty but i its not included.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView list; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listing);

        ArrayList<In_List> data = new ArrayList<>();  

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){

        data.add(new In_List(i, "Item Number :"+i+1, i*2,0));

    }

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_listing);
        list.setAdapter(new List_Adapter(this, R.layout.entry, data){
            @Override
            public void onInsert(Object entr, View view) {
                if (entr != null) {
                    TextView id_Text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_id); 
                    if (id_Text != null) 
                        id_Text.setText(((In_List) entr).get_id()); 

                    TextView info_Text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_info); 
                    if (info_Text != null)
                        info_Text.setText(((In_List) entr).get_text()); 

                    TextView inside_Text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_inside); 
                    if (inside_Text != null)
                        inside_Text.setText(((In_List) entr).get_a()); 

                TextView Qty_Text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_qty); 
                    if (Qty_Text != null || Qty_Text.getText().toString().equals(0))
                        Qty_Text.setText(((In_List) entr).get_Qty()); 

                Qty_Text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Add_Qty();
                    }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

//        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
//          @Override
//          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//              In_List chosen = (In_List) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 
//
//                CharSequence text = "Selected: " + chosen.get_textoDebajo();
//                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, texto, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
//                toast.show();
//          }
//        });

    }

}
```

now, when i scroll down through the list the Qtys that i have entered either disappear or move to another row.

fixed. i wasn't stablishing Qty_Text value at all. also made a method to save into the adapter array.

Comment: this is because of the view recycling in the listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EditTexts in generally are very tricky. And using them inside a ListView is almost impossible. The special behaviour of EditTexts for example to always automatically assume focus combinded with the View recycling of the ListViews messes with the ListView and causes a lot of problems. I would suggest you look for another solution. For example placing the EditText inside the HeaderView of the ListView is fine, as the HeaderView is not recycled as you scroll through the ListView.

Comment: thanks for the answer now i need to look at how i can do that because i need to enter values inside one of those edit texts, i guess ill use a clicklistener and make a window pop when someone clicks a row of the list.

Comment: Yes that's how I often work around this issue. Dialogs or DialogFragments are a good solution.

Comment: well it seems like some of the problems are fixed but the scrolling problem still persists im guessing the problem is my adapter but i cant paste the code atm.

Comment: As soon as you are able to post your code I can try to find the error.